# Reading file in C

Tags: c, string

I'm reading a file in my C program and comparing every word in it with my word, which is entered via command line argument. But I get crashes, and I can't understand what's wrong. How do I track such errors? What is wrong in my case?

My compiler is clang. The code compiles fine. When running it says 'segmentation fault'.

Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* temp = argv[1];
    char* word = strcat(temp, "\n");

    char* c = "abc";
    FILE *input = fopen("/usr/share/dict/words", "r");

    while (strcmp(word, c))
    {
        char* duh = fgets(c, 20, input);
        printf("%s", duh); 
    }

    if (!strcmp (word, c))
    {
        printf("FOUND IT!\n");
        printf("%s\n%s", word, c);  
    }

    fclose(input);    
}
```

Comment: What's your compiler? what's debugger?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438941/comparing-and-checking-columns-in-two-files/13440245#13440245

Comment: And regarding the crash, you can't use `strcat` with an argument as destination! It should be considered a read-only string. What you are doing now is overwriting memory not allocated for the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to treat strings in C as you might in another language (like C++ or Java), in which they are resizable vectors that you can easily append or read an arbitrary amount of data into.

C strings are much lower level. They are simply an array of characters (or a pointer to such an array; arrays can be treated like pointers to their first element in C anyhow), and the string is treated as all of the characters within that array up to the first null character. These arrays are fixed size; if you want a string of an arbitrary size, you need to allocate it yourself using `malloc()`, or allocate it on the stack with the size that you would like.

One thing here that is a little confusing is you are using a non-standard type `string`. Given the context, I'm assuming that's coming from your `cs50.h`, and is just a typedef to `char *`. It will probably reduce confusion if you actually use `char *` instead of `string`; using a typedef obscures what's really going on.

Let's start with the first problem.

```
    string word = strcat(argv[1], "\n");
```

`strcat()` appends the second string onto the first; it starts from the null terminator of the first string, and replaces that with the first character of the second string, and so on, until it reaches a null in the second string. In order for this to work, the buffer containing the first string needs to have enough room to fit the second one. If it does not, you may overwrite arbitrary other memory, which could cause your program to crash or have all kinds of other unexpected behavior.

Here's an illustration. Let's say that `argv[1]` contains the word `hello`, and the buffer has exactly as much space as it needs for this. After it is some other data; I've filled in `other` for the sake of example, though it won't actually be that, it could be anything, and it may or may not be important:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| h | e | l | l | o | \0| o | t | h | e | r | \0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Now if you use `strcat()` to append `"\n"`, you will get:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| h | e | l | l | o | \n| \0| t | h | e | r | \0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

You can see that we've overwritten the `other` data that was after `hello`. This may cause all kinds of problems. To fix this, you need to copy your `argv[1]` into a new string, that has enough room for it plus one more character (and don't forget the trailing null). You can call `strlen()` to get the length of the string, then add 1 for the `\n`, and one for the trailing null, to get the length that you need.

Actually, instead of trying to add a `\n` to the word you get in from the command line, I would recommend stripping off the `\n` from your input words, or using `strncmp()` to compare all but the last character (the `\n`). In general, it's best in C to avoid appending strings, as appending strings means you need to allocate memory and copy things around, and it can be easy to make mistakes doing so, as well as being inefficient. Higher level languages usually take care of the details for you, making it easier to append strings, though still just as inefficient.

After your edit, you changed this to:

```
    char* temp = argv[1];
    char* word = strcat(temp, "\n");
```

However, this has the same problem. A `char *` is a pointer to a character array. Your `temp` variable is just copying the pointer, not the actual value; it is still pointing to the same buffer. Here's an illustration; I'm making up addresses for the purposes of demonstration, in the real machine there will be more objects in between these things, but this should suffice for the purpose of demonstration.

```
+------------+---------+-------+
|    name    | address | value |
+------------+---------+-------+
| argv       |    1000 |  1004 |-------+
| argv[0]    |    1004 |  1008 | --+ <-+
| argv[1]    |    1006 |  1016 | --|---+
| argv[0][0] |    1008 |   'm' | <-+   |
| argv[0][1] |    1009 |   'y' |       |
| argv[0][2] |    1010 |   'p' |       |
| argv[0][3] |    1011 |   'r' |       |
| argv[0][4] |    1012 |   'o' |       |
| argv[0][5] |    1013 |   'g' |       |
| argv[0][6] |    1014 |     0 |       |
| argv[1][0] |    1016 |   'w' | <-+ <-+
| argv[1][1] |    1017 |   'o' |   |
| argv[1][2] |    1018 |   'r' |   |
| argv[1][3] |    1019 |   'd' |   |
| argv[1][4] |    1020 |     0 |   |
+------------+---------+-------+   |
```

Now when you create your `temp` variable, all you are doing is copying `argv[1]` into a new `char *`:

```
+------------+---------+-------+   | 
|    name    | address | value |   |
+------------+---------+-------+   |
| temp       |    1024 |  1016 | --+
+------------+---------+-------+
```

As a side note, you also shouldn't ever try to access `argv[1]` without checking that `argc` is greater than 1. If someone doesn't pass any arguments in, then `argv[1]` itself is invalid to access.

I'll move on to the next problem.

```
    string c = "abc";

    // ...

        char* duh = fgets(c, 20, input);
```

Here, you are referring to the static string `"abc"`. A string that appears literally in the source, like `"abc"`, goes into a special, read-only part of the memory of the program. Remember what I said; `string` here is just a way of saying `char *`. So `c` is actually just a pointer into this read-only section of memory; and it has only enough room to store the characters that you provided in the text (4, for `abc` and the null character terminating the string). `fgets()` takes as its first argument a place to store the string that it is reading, and its second the amount of space that it has. So you are trying to read up to 20 bytes, into a read-only buffer that only has room for 4.

You need to either allocate space for reading on the stack, using, for example:

```
char c[20];
```

Or dynamically, using `malloc()`:

```
char *c = malloc(20);
```

Answer (score 1):

First problem I see is this:

```
string word = strcat(argv[1], "\n");
```

You are adding characters to the end of a buffer here.
A buffer allocated for you by the runtime enviroment, that you should consider read only.

**EDIT**

I'm afraid your change to the code still has the same effect.

```
char* temp = argv[1];
```

Has `temp` pointing to the same buffer as `argv[1]`.
You need to allocate a buffer the proper size, and use it.

```
char* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(argv[1]) + 2));
```

The `+2` is for the adding `\n` and `\0` at the end.
Than you do this:

```
strcpy(temp, argv[1]);
strcat(temp,"\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is rather flawed. Another one:

```
char* duh = fgets(c, 20, input);
```

Here you define a pointer to char, do not initialize it (hence it contains a random value) and then you write up to 20 bytes to the address pointed to by the random data. If you're lucky you just get a cash. If not, you overwrite some other important data. Fortunately most of the systems in use today won't let you access address space of another program, so the code wreaks havoc only on itself.

The line in question could look like:

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 1024
...
while (reasonable condition) {
    char *duh = malloc(BUFERSIZE);
    if (NULL == duh) { /* not enough memory - handle error, and exit */
    }
    duh = fgets(duh, BUFFERSIZE, input);
    if (NULL == duh) { /* handle error or EOF condition */
    } else { /* check that the line is read completely,
        i.e. including end-of-line mark,
        then do your stuff with the data */
    }
    free (duh);
}
```

Of course, you can allocate the buffer only once (outside of the loop) and reuse it. The `#define` makes it easy to adjust the maximum buffer size.

Alternatively, on recent systems, you can use `getline()`, which is able to allocate a buffer of appropriate size for you. That you **must** `free()` at the end of the loop.

If you are on Linux/BSD, use `man` (e.g. `man fgets`) to get information on the functions, otherwise resort to internet or a decent book on C for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First, My C knowledge is old, so I'm not sure what a string is. Either way, it's helpful, but not absolutely required to have a nice pre-zeroed buffer in which to read contents of the file. So whether you zero `word` or do something like the following, zero the input first.

```
#define IN_BUF_LEN 120
char in_buf[IN_BUF_LEN] = {0};
```

120 characters is a safe size, assuming most of your text lines are around 80 characters or less long.

Second, you're basing your loop of the value of a `strcmp` rather than actually reading the file. It might accomplish the same thing, but I'd base my `while` on reaching end of file.

Finally, you've declared `duh` a pointer, not a place to store what `fgets` returns. That's a problem, too. So, `duh` should be declared similarly to `in_buf` above.

Finally, you're assigning the value of `argv[1]` at compile time, not run-time. I can't see where that's getting you what you want. If you declare `temp` as a pointer and then assign `argv[1]` to it, you'll just have another pointer to `argv[1]`, but not actually have copied the value of `argv[1]` to a local variable. Why not just use `argv[1]`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'assigning the value of `argv[1]` at compile time, not run-time'; frankly, that's balderdash — the assignment only occurs at run-time.